# Can't seem to call javascript in blazor

Tags: javascript, css, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I am trying to use JSinterop but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am trying to implement a back to the top button, using this codepen example
https://codepen.io/rdallaire/pen/apoyx

I have added the CSS And Javascript file to the host file.. And they are being bought into the screen when loading up the site. But the button never appears on my screen.

Had to slightly tweek the JS so that it can be called by JsInterop

```
// ===== Scroll to Top ==== 
function scrollToTopFunc() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) { // If page is scrolled more than 50px
            $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200); // Fade in the arrow
        } else {
            $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200); // Else fade out the arrow
        }
    });
    $('#return-to-top').click(function() { // When arrow is clicked
        $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0 // Scroll to top of body
            },
            500);
    });
}
```

Added to my page

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;
```

And the call to the javascript

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{

    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToTopFunc");
}
```

And added the  tag to the page

```
<a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

Now when i load the page, i get no errors in the google dev tools. Really confused. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: If you put a `console.log('in scrollToTopFunc');` and a `console.log('in return-to-top');` in there can you verify that the javascript is at least getting called?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this without the use of a javascript file eventually by doing the below

<button class="newHomeButton newHomeButton--secondary" data-ste-component="conversion-main" aria-label="" **onClick="document.getElementById('main').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'})"** cur>

I just wrapped my header in a div with the id="Main" and the job was a good one.